# For loop with GET methods and CouchDB operations inside async.js series not executing more than once

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, get, couchdb, async.js

I am making consecutive http get calls using async.js series, all of which is inside a for loop. First I retrieve a number of results from an API query, then I run another query on each of the results. The results are stored in an array and then saved to a CouchDB database. Because the number of results is limited to 200, I have to do this multiple times (hence the for loop). The basic structure of the code is as follows (full code below)

```
for (...) {
  async.series(
     [
       function(){ http get method }, 
       function (){ async.eachSeries(){ http get method }, callback function }
     ],
     function(){ database operations }
  );//end series
}//end for loop
```

My problem is that the loop executes only once. Everything inside the  loop works as expected, and the data is saved correctly to the database--but I can't figure out why the loop won't run again. I know if I put a method call in the async callback function it will run fine, so maybe I am missing something about how async works. I think that the for loop should be on the call stack, so when async is done, the loop should simply continue, but this obviously isn't the case.

Full code:

```
for (var retstart = 0; retstart < elsvr_count; retstart += elsvr_retSize) { 

var elsvr_resultChunk;

async.series(
    [ 
        function(callback){

            var elsvr_Query = String(elsvr_baseURL) + "apiKey="+ String(elsvr_apiKey) + "&query=af-id(" + String(elsvr_ID) + ")&httpAccept=application/" + String(elsvr_resultType) + "&count=" + String(elsvr_retSize) + "&view=";

            $.get(elsvr_Query, function(result) {

                elsvr_count = parseInt(result["search-results"]["opensearch:totalResults"]); //the number of results
                console.log("count set at " + elsvr_count);
                elsvr_resultChunk = result["search-results"]["entry"]; //the current chunk of the total result, the size of which elsvr_retSize
                callback(null);
            });//end get

        },

        function(callback){

            async.eachSeries(elsvr_resultChunk, function(item, callback){
                var docQuery = item["prism:url"] + "?apiKey=" + String(elsvr_apiKey) + "&httpAccept=application/" + String(elsvr_resultType);

                $.ajax({
                    url: docQuery,
                    type: 'GET',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function(result){
                        elsvr_results.push(result);
                        return callback(null);
                    },
                    error: function(err){
                        console.log("error returned: "+err.statusText);
                        elsvr_errors = elsvr_errors+1;
                        return callback(null);
                    }
                });
            },

            function(err, results) {
                if (err) console.log("error: " + err);
                else
                    callback(null, elsvr_results);
            });

        }
    ],

    //callback from async.series
    function (err, results){
        if (err)
            console.log("ERROR: " + JSON.stringify(err));
        else {
            db.getDoc('unprocessed', function(er, doc){
                if (er) throw new Error(JSON.stringify(er));

                if (doc.elsvr != undefined)
                    doc.elsvr = _.extend(results[1], doc.elsvr);
                else
                    doc.elsvr = results[1];

                db.saveDoc('unprocessed', doc, function(er, ok) {
                    if (er) throw new Error(JSON.stringify(er));
                    console.log('saved a chunk to the database: ' + db.name);
                });
            });
        }
     }
);//end async.series
}//end for loop
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I finally solved it. Turns out the loop was not executing synchronously, and since I update the loop conditional (elsvr_count) *inside the async series*, the loop was finished before the conditional was actually set properly. However, that wasn't the only issue--if I removed that conditional update and simply set elsvr_count to be a high number outside the loop, the loop would still run asynchronously before the async series returned.

I'll post my solution in case anyone else runs into a similar problem: Basically, replace the for loop with an async.whilst loop as follows

```
        async.whilst(function() { return retstart < elsvr_count; }, 
            function(callback) {
                var elsvr_resultChunk;
                async.series(

                      //...
                      //same stuff as above goes here
                      //...

                      //save the document to the database
                      db.saveDoc('unprocessed', doc, function(er, ok) {
                          if (er) throw new Error(JSON.stringify(er));
                          retstart += elsvr_retSize; //<-- to replace the increment of the for loop
                          callback(null); //<-- important     
                      });

                      //...
                      //...
                );//end async.series
            },

           //callback for the whilst loop. this will be called once the condition is no longer met (retstart < elsvr_retSize)
           function(err) {
               //do stuff in here
           }
        );//end async.whilst
```